# Append number in textbox on submit

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add two zeros to any number entered in a textbox when submitted. 
For instance, if i enter 34 in a textbox and click on submit, it should be saved as 3400.

Could this be done on the fly too?

Comment: And if someone entered `3400`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do after the submit. Especially: Do you want to interpret this as a number and simply multiply by 100 (34 * 100) or do you want to simply append something to the value? ("34" + "00")?

In the first case you would do this:

```
<input id="value" type="number" value="34"/>
<br>
<button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>


 <script>
  function submit() {
      const input = document.getElementById("value");
      const value = input.attributes.value;

      input.value = parseInt(input.value) * 100;
  }
</script>
```

In the second case this:

```
<input id="value" type="number" value="34"/>
<br>
<button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>

 <script>
  function submit() {
      const input = document.getElementById("value");
      const value = input.attributes.value;

      input.value = input.value.toString() + '00';
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit vague, but it sounds like you're looking for something like the following.

```js
// Gather each element from the HTML, so you can access its input or update its display:
const input = document.getElementById('numberInput');
const button = document.getElementById('submit');
const display1 = document.getElementById('display1');
const display2 = document.getElementById('display2');

// Add a click event to the button, which gathers the text field value, ensures it's a number, and updates the display as requested:
button.addEventListener('click',() => {
  const value = input.value;
  
  // This if statement ensures that only numbers will be suffixed with be suffixed with two zeros:
  if (isNaN(value)) {
     alert('Please enter a valid number');
     return;
  }
  
  // Update the display span's contents as requested.  There are many ways of doing this.  Here are a few;

  // Here I'm taking the submitted value, and nesting it inside a string, alongside the two zeros.  In cases of Infinity or .100, the result will still be the input suffixed with two zeros:
  display1.innerHTML = `${value}00`;
  
  // This method, on the other hand, will simply move the decimal to columns:
  display2.innerHTML = value * 100;
});
```

```html
<p> 
  Display 1: <span id="display1"></span>
</p>
<p>
  Display 2: <span id="display2"></span>
</p>
<input type="text" id="numberInput">
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Exactly what i wanted! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could always set an event listener that changes the number on exit of the form element, so something like this:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', watchNums);

function watchNums() {
    document.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', watchNums);
    
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('number')).map(
        number => {
            number.addEventListener('blur', _ => {
                number.value = parseInt(number.value) * 100;
            })
        }
    )
}
```

```html
<body>
    <form action="/endpoint.htm" method="POST">
        <input type="number" name="number-input" class="number">
        <input type="number" name="other-number-input" class="number">
        <button type="submit">Submit Numbers</button>
    </form>
</body>
```